# Cannot connect to svn server via Tortoise

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have run an svn server on my ubuntu server and created a repository following this tutorial: http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/

I tried to checkout the repository as follows:

```
$ svn checkout file:///usr/local/svn/repos/test
Checked out revision 0.
```

It works properly and I got the above message but I cannot access to the svn repository via TortoiseSVN on windows and the error bellow is occurred while trying to access:

[image]

It sounds that svn server does not listen to the port 3690!

Answer (score 1):

Is something blocking port 3690? That's the port that svnserve uses by default.

I had the firewall blocking it. So, I disabled it and called svnserve with "--listen-host 0.0.0.0" and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes, probably just the firewall blocking the request.